# How / where is the  wp_query object created for RSS feeds?

Tags: comments, loop, rss

Looking at the code in feed-rss2.php and feeds-rss2-comments.php, after the header preamble, we have a Loop - eg in feeds-rss2-comments.php:

```
if ( have_comments() ) : while ( have_comments() ) : the_comment();
$comment_post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
get_post_custom($comment_post->ID);
```

Where is the wp_comment_query object being created for this loop?

What I'm doing (following my question yesterday), is creating 2 new RSS feeds - one showing posts that have been trashed, the other showing comments that have been trashed. It's easy enough to add a new query_posts / get_comments call, but is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are not loaded directly, but similar to regular template files, only after the `WP` class is initialized. This class does the main query, which already can include the comments if the correct query variables are set.

The execution flow is a follows, starting in the main `index.php`:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
        // Initialization of settings, plugins, theme
    wp();
        WP::main();
            WP::init();
            WP::parse_request();
                // Parse `/feed/` and `/comments/feed/` and set the query variables
            WP::send_headers();
            WP::query_posts();
                WP::build_query_string();
                WP_Query::query();
                    WP_Query::init();
                    WP_Query::get_posts();
                        // This does the actual query
                        // `pre_get_posts` is the action you'll probably want to use
            WP::handle_404();
            WP::register_globals();
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
        if ( is_feed() ) {
            do_feed();
                // This calls the `do_feed_[feedtype]` action, e.g. rss2
                    do_feed_rss2( $for_comments );
                        if ( $for_comments )
                            load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed-rss2-comments.php' );
                        else
                            load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed-rss2.php' );
        }
```